# "onFocus" prop is not changing properly between two text fields

Tags: reactjs, onfocus

I need to move the cursor from textfield1 to textfield2 when I press the "Enter" from textfield1 and I need to move the cursor from textfield2 to textfield1  when I press the "Enter" from textfield2. 
States are changing properly when I press "Enter" from textfield2 and textField2, but the cursor doesn't move between text fields.

Here is my code.

```
export default class BasicTextFields extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.one = this.one.bind(this);
    this.two = this.two.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      one: true,
      two: false,
    };
  }

  one(e) {
    console.log(e.key);
    if (e.key == 'Enter') {
      this.setState(
        {
          two: true,
          one: false,
        },
        () => {
          console.log(this.state);
        }
      );
    }
  }

  two(e) {
    if (e.key == 'Enter') {
      this.setState(
        {
          two: false,
          one: true,
        },
        () => {
          console.log(this.state);
        }
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Box>
        <TextField
          onKeyDown={this.one}
          autoFocus={this.state.one}
          id='filled-basic'
          label='Filled'
          variant='filled'
        />

        <TextField
          onKeyDown={this.two}
          autoFocus={this.state.two}
          id='standard-basic'
          label='Standard'
          variant='standard'
        />
      </Box>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the `<TextField>` component?

Comment: import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For DOM manipulations, as for managing the focus of input elements, you can use *[React Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)*.

Using React Refs — assuming your refs are called respectively *inputOne* and *inputTwo* — you will be able to call `this.inputTwo.current.focus()` to put the focus on the second input. For information, the property *current* of the Ref returns the HTML DOM node.

One more thing to keep in mind is, since your `<input>` tags are in a children component, but you need to control focus from the parent of both inputs, you'll have to declare the refs in the parent, and forward the references thanks to `React.forwardRef`. See also [Forwarding Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

Here is the **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8ywruh)**