# "Focus" prop is not changing properly between text fields in a array

Tags: reactjs, ref, autofocus

I need to move the cursor downwards in the array of text fields when the "Enter" button is pressed. States change properly when I press "Enter", but the cursor doesn't move.

here is my code

```
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default class BasicTextFields extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      cursor_index: 0,
      arr: ["sampledata", "sampledata", "sampledata"]
    };
    this.one = this.one.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
   
  }

  one(e, index) {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      this.setState({
        cursor_index: index + 1
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.arr.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <TextField
              autoFocus={index == this.state.cursor_index}
              onKeyDown={(e) => {
                this.one(e, index);
              }}
              id="filled-basic"
              label="Filled"
              variant="filled"
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["onFocus" prop is not changing properly between two text fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69756040/onfocus-prop-is-not-changing-properly-between-two-text-fields)

Comment: Please do not create multiple accounts to re-post or edit your posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep a `refs array` in parallel to your data array and use that information to focus on `next text input`.

Pressing `enter` at the last input filed will get back to the first input again. You can change these edge conditions as you need.

Try below

```
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import React, { createRef } from "react";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      cursor_index: 0,
      arr: ["sampledata", "sampledata", "sampledata"],
      refs: [createRef(), createRef(), createRef()]
    };
    this.one = this.one.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {}

  one(e, index) {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      const { arr, refs } = this.state;
      console.log();
      refs[(index + 1) % arr.length].current.focus();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.arr.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <TextField
              onKeyDown={(e) => {
                this.one(e, index);
              }}
              inputRef={this.state.refs[index]}
              id="filled-basic"
              label="Filled"
              variant="filled"
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/small-waterfall-uh7p4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Great, thank you very much, but the array is not static. So that how can I implement "createRef()"?

Comment: You can structure it like this. Create a new component for InputFiled (it will be a TextField or SelectionInput ....etc) and Form. The form will get an array of information as input fields and it creates the refs array depending on the number of inputs in your form.